# combining two data frames of different sizes and names

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello i have a question about data frames. Lets say I have a data frame `diamonds_2[5000,5]` where my columns are `carat, color, clarity, price, cut` . I created a new data frame named results where i computed the average price for every combination of color and cut  with the following command:

```
results<tapply(diamonds_2$price,list(diamonds_2$color,diamonds_2$cut),mean)
results <- data.frame(results)
```

Now I am trying to create a data frame by combining the original data frame `diamonds_2` with the result data frame so that for every diamond, you see the price and next to it also the average price (based on combination of color and cut). I think i have to use the merge command but I m confused because i do not know how to use the by.x or by.y command. Because my results data frame on the one axis(the rows) has the colors(D,E,F,G,J,I,K) and on other axis(the columns) has the cut variables( above average, below average, very good)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this a slightly different way. You need an `inner_join` from `dplyr`. The `dplyr` package can also do the first part of your work, too.  It looks like your `diamonds_2` data is a subset of the builtin `diamonds` dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
# building data with columns like yours
diamonds_2 <- diamonds %>% select(carat, color, clarity, price, cut)
# I'll do the summary stats within the join to avoid having to make a new object in memory
diamonds_2 %>%
  left_join(diamonds_2 %>%
              group_by(color, cut) %>%
              summarize(mean_price = mean(price)))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'color' (override with `.groups` argument)
Joining, by = c("color", "cut")
# A tibble: 53,940 x 6
   carat color clarity price cut       mean_price
   <dbl> <ord> <ord>   <int> <ord>          <dbl>
 1 0.23  E     SI2       326 Ideal          2598.
 2 0.21  E     SI1       326 Premium        3539.
 3 0.23  E     VS1       327 Good           3424.
 4 0.290 I     VS2       334 Premium        5946.
 5 0.31  J     SI2       335 Good           4574.
 6 0.24  J     VVS2      336 Very Good      5104.
 7 0.24  I     VVS1      336 Very Good      5256.
 8 0.26  H     SI1       337 Very Good      4535.
 9 0.22  E     VS2       337 Fair           3682.
10 0.23  H     VS1       338 Very Good      4535.
# ... with 53,930 more rows
```

Comment: oh that solved the problem quite fast! Thank you very much. Just by curiosity because i m learning R now, can i do it without tibble? Ok i can do it with hard coding but there should be a function that would do it automatically

Comment: If you don't want it to be a tibble, you can always us `as.data.frame()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tapply`, consider `ave` for inline aggregation without collapsing rows to assign new column.

```
diamonds_2$avg_price <- with(diamonds_2, ave(price, color, cut, FUN=mean))
```

---

Since you may be versed in Python, this is similar to `groupby.transform`:

```py
diamonds_2['avg_price'] = diamonds_2.groupby(['color', 'cut'])['price'].transform('mean')
```

Or even SQL's window function (check with R's `sqldf` or Python's `pandasql`)

```sql
SELECT color
       , cut
       , AVG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY color, cut) AS avg_price
FROM diamonds_2
```